# Error when connecting iOS app to parse: Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am new to iOS and Parse and have successfully utilized the service for one of my current apps. However, I have started a second app and when I go to connect the app to parse (using application ID and client key) I am getting 4 errors. They read as:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFExecutor_$_Background in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPush.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFRetryingCommandRunner.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFTask_$_Private in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Could you upload the source code?

Comment: #import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"dUiZ4Cs9ya2L9kmgCVpotlA1pfc2wTX4s0Q2Ig4I"
                  clientKey:@"PHhkbn8o7fwprBg3Da0jPi5K2QfirR4hUmZNlAur"];
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 86):

You forgot to add [Bolts.framework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC) . Please add it. All the errors shall be fixed after that.

Comment: At first,  I was struggling finding out where Bolts.framework is.  It is located in the Parse SDK download zip mentioned here: https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Comment: I have missed the line "Drag the Parse.framework AND Bolts.framework you downloaded into your Xcode project folder target."

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me! Ha, completely forgot to add that framework!

Comment: In there tutorial here https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/native/existing they never mentioned that wen need to add bolt.framework. That worked but.